# How to add DEM data(.tif) in a shape file in gdal with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, gdal, matplotlib-basemap

i have plotted a map with shape file in basemap, on the basis of this, i want to add the DEM data(.tif) in the map. i have download a piece of .tif data (longitude and latitude was really inside the range of the shapefile) in the SRTM website, but finally when i run the program,it did not show the raster data in the specific loction of the map

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from osgeo import gdal
from numpy import linspace
from numpy import meshgrid

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=80)
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,1.0,1.0])
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=114.7, 
          llcrnrlat=29.3, 
          urcrnrlon=120, 
          urcrnrlat=34.6,
         resolution='h', projection='tmerc', lat_0 =31.5,lon_0=116.5,ax=ax1)
shp_info =  map.readshapefile("bou2_4l",'state',color='k',linewidth='1',drawbounds=True)

ds = gdal.Open("srtm_60_06.tif")
data = ds.ReadAsArray()
loc3=[30,35]
lat3=[115,120]
x1,y1 = map(loc3,lat3)
x = linspace(x1[0],x1[1], data.shape[1])
y = linspace(y1[0],y1[1], data.shape[0])
xx, yy = meshgrid(x, y)
map.pcolormesh(xx, yy, data)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a more concise answer if you asked this over at gis.stackexchange.

Anyhow, this seems like a projection error to me. I stand to be corrected but the STRM tiffs are GeoTiffs so they have the projection information in the header.

It looks like you are using Transverse Mercator while the SRTM data uses a geographic coordinate system.

Try reprojecting your TIFF, I think gdal.Warp should do it:

```
gdal.Warp(output_raster,input_raster,dstSRS='EPSG:your_basemap_projection')
```